# Optional url segment pattern in a Pyramid route

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to create a website with optional url sub-paths:

- /user - Returns general information on users
- /user/edit - Edits the user

I've tried setting:

```
config.add_route('user', '/user/{action}')

@view_defaults(route_name="user")
class UserViews():

# not sure what (if anything) to put in @view_config here...
def user_general(self):
    return Response("General User Info"

@view_config(match_param="action=edit")
def edit(self):
    return Response("Editing user")
```

However while this works for `/user/edit`, it returns a 404 for `/user`

It also fails in the same way if I set 2 explicit routes with a shared path - e.g.:

```
config.add_route('login', '/user')
config.add_route('edit_user', '/user/edit')
```

I've tried things like setting `match_params="action="` but can't get it to work.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I have a vague feeling that you're trying to reinvent Pyramid's "traversal" mechanism (https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html)

What if "user" was some sort of "UserResource" which would provide all common logic your view class now provides and the two views were registered in the "context" of the  UserResource?

Comment: After looking at your code I'm wondering if you tried accessing `/user/` - I think your "user_general" view should be there

Answer (score 3):

`user_general` inherits the default route configuration of the class, which requires an `{action}` match param. When you do not supply that in the request, the route for that view will never match, returning a 404 not found response.

You need to add a decorator with the `route_name` argument to `user_general` to override the default route for the view.

```python
@view_config(
    route_name="user"
)
def user_general(self):
```

The following works for me as a complete example with some minor explicit naming conventions.

```python
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config, view_defaults


@view_defaults(route_name="user_action")
class UserViews():
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.request = request
        self.context = context

    @view_config(
        route_name="user_get",
        request_method="GET"
    )
    def get_user(request):
        return Response("I got you, Babe!")

    @view_config(
        match_param="action=edit"
    )
    def edit(self):
        return Response("Don't ever change, Babe!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route("user_get", "/user")
        config.add_route('user_action', '/user/{action}')
        config.scan()
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server("0.0.0.0", 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```